# October CMS AJAX actions - plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

What could be the problem if I get this error when I try to call an AJAX action?

> Invalid handler name. The correct handler name format is: "onEvent"

I am trying to use contact form plugin and it's not working because of this AJAX call error. I included `{% framework %}` and `{% framework extras %}` in my main template at the very bottom, right after the jQuery includes. I use the contact form in another partial which is included in that main template. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/handlers#ajax-handlers):

> Handler names should have the following pattern: onName

Is your handler name following that pattern?

Answer (score 1):

So in october cms the ajax handlers names should be onName
example

```
<button data-request="onGallery" >Go</button>
```

and in Ajax handler

```
public function onGallery()
```

{

```
     flash::success('hi');
```

}

according to the document all the handlers should have on preceding the name of the function